# How do you checkout from github using Intellij IDEA if you're not the project owner

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I attempted to clone a git repository from github for a client using Intellij IDEA.  My github account is a collaborator on the repository, but IDEA doesn't show it.  It only shows repositories that I am the owner of.

I can clone the repo from the command line using msys git, but IDEA fails checking out as a plain git repository too.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using? If I remember correctly, the issue with checking out the repository as a collaborator is fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 10.5 EAP:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/index.html